# React Native : What are the Build.Gradle settings to specify the latest version (post 0.20.1)?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I am Following the instructions in http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-android.html to add react native screens inside existing android app but using offline bundle instead of JS being part of the Android App.

Specifying the following in build.gradle:
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" only gets the version of 0.20.1. 
[Both Maven and JCenter seem to have that: https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.facebook.react:react-native/view as well as http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.react/react-native seem to have 0.20.1]

Since I am using 0.27.1 features in my js code, want to use the same version in android. Specifying 0.27.1, or 0.26.1 all throw up errors : could not resolve dependency.

How do I get gradle to use the latest react-native version?

Comment: Discussed more in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7832